# collectd stores NaN instead of correct value in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, rrdtool, collectd

I installed collectd using sudo apt-get install collectd on my ubuntu 12.04, but it just collect NaN values in the rrd files. for example for file named memory-used.rrd this is the values it saved.

0003
    10 
    1366005779

```
<ds>
    <name> value </name>
    <type> GAUGE </type>
    <minimal_heartbeat>20</minimal_heartbeat>
    <min>0.0000000000e+00</min>
    <max>2.8147497671e+14</max>

    <!-- PDP Status -->
    <last_ds>1807986688.000000</last_ds>
    <value>1.6271880192e+10</value>
    <unknown_sec> 0 </unknown_sec>
</ds>

<!-- Round Robin Archives -->
<rra>
    <cf>AVERAGE</cf>
    <pdp_per_row>1</pdp_per_row> <!-- 10 seconds -->

    <params>
    <xff>1.0000000000e-01</xff>
    </params>
    <cdp_prep>
        <ds>
        <primary_value>1.8075664384e+09</primary_value>
        <secondary_value>0.0000000000e+00</secondary_value>
        <value>NaN</value>
        <unknown_datapoints>0</unknown_datapoints>
        </ds>
    </cdp_prep>
    <database>
        <!-- 2013-04-15 07:13:00 IRDT / 1365993780 --> <row><v>NaN</v></row>
        <!-- 2013-04-15 07:13:10 IRDT / 1365993790 --> <row><v>NaN</v></row>
        <!-- 2013-04-15 07:13:20 IRDT / 1365993800 --> <row><v>NaN</v></row>
        <!-- 2013-04-15 07:13:30 IRDT / 1365993810 --> <row><v>NaN</v></row>
        <!-- 2013-04-15 07:13:40 IRDT / 1365993820 --> <row><v>NaN</v></row>
        <!-- 2013-04-15 07:13:50 IRDT / 1365993830 --> <row><v>NaN</v></row>
                    .........
</database>
</rra>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quite effective way to troubleshoot collectd:

- enable the fewest possible read plugins (e.g. in your case *memory*)

  ```
  LoadPlugin memory
  ```
- enable *csv* write plugin

  ```
  LoadPlugin csv
  <Plugin csv>
    DataDir "/tmp/collectd-csv"
  </Plugin>
  ```
- enable *logfile* plugin

  ```
  <Plugin logfile>
     File STDOUT
     ## Only available if compiled using --enable-debug
     # LogLevel debug
     ##
     LogLevel info
  </Plugin>
  ```
- run *collectd* in the foreground

  ```
  collectd -C /path/to/collectd.conf -f
  ```
- Look at your *csv* directory, if anything gets reported

If everything looks fine, the next step would be to troubleshoot the *rrdtool* plugin.

Comment: thanks. it helped me a lot, I find out how to figure out the problem. now it works

Comment: @MoeenM What was the issue  ?